# iReport doesn't use the correct values

Tags: mysql, ireport

I have following query which worked fine until another user wants to generate reports. The query gives every information, **but not user specific one**. This confuses me, because when I execute the query in my database, the query works perfectly fine.

```
SELECT date, duration, educationDepartment, completedtasks FROM
programm_completedtask WHERE date BETWEEN $P{Startdatum} AND
$P{Enddatum} AND trainee_id = (SELECT id FROM programm_trainee WHERE
username = $P{username});
```

my **programm_completedtask** looks like this

```
+------------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                     | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| trainee_id             | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date                   | date     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| duration               | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| documentationReference | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| educationDepartment    | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| completedtasks         | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

my **programm_trainee looks** like this

```
+--------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| comment            | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| firstName          | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastName           | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| educationBeginning | date     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username           | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Do you have any suggestions why this is not working out for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an `INNER JOIN` instead of the second `SELECT` statements and now it works.